# Open the app in foreground from Notification Service/Content Extension

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is there any way to open an app in a foreground from Notification Service/Content Extension?

Note: If my app failed to send the data to the server, I like to open an app in a foreground and do the full login process to complete the action taken from Notification Service/Content Extension.

Comment: Open the app without user interaction ? No. You can't.

Comment: I can add a button in Content Extension if that helps. I am just trying to mimic the way notification tap works.

Comment: That’s the problem. If you tap a notification you have an user interaction with your app. Adding a button is the same. Opening the app programmatically through notification is not possible. Thinking on UX, I can’t imagine the nightmare to have apps opening by theirselves on my phone